# Why does YoloV8 perform poorly when exported to .onnx and run with onnxruntime or opencv dnn? The results just don't compare to torch .pt model files

Tags: object-detection, torch, yolo, onnx, onnxruntime

I'm working on transfer learning a coco trained yolov8 model to detect objects in an entirely different use case. I get really encouraging performance metrics when I reload the trained model from its model.pt file using the ultralytics library and inbuilt functions.

However, I have tried to export the model to .onnx and failed to achieve the same metrics.

- I trained it on rectangular images of size 1280,720 with the flags rect=True, imgsz=1280
- I exported it like this: `yolo task=detect mode=export model=runs/detect/last.pt imgsz=720,1280 simplify=true format=onnx opset=12`
- I tried without an opset, opset11 and opset12 (official docs recommend opset12)
- I tried to export it with and without simplify
- I've tried to use onnxruntime library using this github repo [here](https://github.com/ibaiGorordo/ONNX-YOLOv8-Object-Detection) as an example
- I tried to use this python example by [ultralytics](https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics/tree/main/examples/YOLOv8-OpenCV-ONNX-Python) themselves

None of the approaches above have given me the same results as using predict.py and loading the model from the original .pt file. Has anyone been able to produce the same results with .onnx as they did with their .pt model and on the gpu? If yes, can you share how you did it?

Comment: This is my training command if it helps:

`yolo detect train data=data/custom.yaml model=yolov8n.pt epochs=100 imgsz=1280 rect=True device=0 batch=8`

Comment: What is the performance drop you get @moonboi?

Comment: The ultralytics package will resize the image and convert it to a numpy array. You will need to do the same if you haven’t already.

Answer (score 3):

Facing same issue here. Export it using opset=12 or even without it. Poorly performance when using opencv onnx model.
But the problems seems to sit on opencv. I don't know what happens under the hood.
If I try to use exported onnx model with Ultralytics Yolo it worked perfectly fine.

```
from ultralytics import YOLO

import cv2

model = YOLO("../runs/detect/train/weights/best.onnx")

im2 = cv2.imread("1.png")
results = model.predict(source=im2, save=True, save_txt=True, imgsz=1280)  # save predictions as labels

for result in results:
    boxes = result.boxes  # Boxes object for bbox outputs
    masks = result.masks  # Masks object for segmentation masks outputs
    probs = result.probs  # Class probabilities for classification outputs
```

Even loading onnx model, it performs exactly as loading .pt model.

Answer (score 1):

As Brian Low mentioned you need to handle the pre-processing that is done in python to create the model input.

e.g. from the ultralytics example you linked, the pre-processing is done in these lines: https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics/blob/3c88bebc9514a4d7f70b771811ddfe3a625ef14d/examples/YOLOv8-OpenCV-ONNX-Python/main.py#L23C57-L31

Note that this involves a number of steps that are not necessarily trivial and need to be done in the same order as what was done to the input when the model was trained. Resize needs to use anti-aliasing. Normalization needs to use the right range (pytorch is usually float from 0..1, tensorflow is usually float from -1..1). The ordering of the data needs to be correct (channels first vs channels last, RGB vs BGR).

However it is possible to add the pre/post processing to the ONNX model so the input is the bytes from a jpeg or png image. See https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime-extensions/blob/main/tutorials/yolo_e2e.py, which happens to be an example for YOLO v8. You will also need the onnxruntime-extensions package for the custom operator that does the image decoding/encoding.

The pre/post processing steps provided are composable and configurable so they can be adjusted as needed and used for a wide range of models (image, text, audio).

e.g. you may want to handle drawing bounding boxes yourself so you could update the post-processing pipeline to stop after the ScaleBoundingBoxes step here so the model output is the best bounding boxes, with co-ordinates that match the original image pre-resizing: https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime-extensions/blob/169438999cf66bd700207441b07c5d26634e72a5/onnxruntime_extensions/tools/add_pre_post_processing_to_model.py#L255-L278

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue using "ort.InferenceSession" on javascript, I've also checked whether it was the datatype, thought that model.onnx used lower numerical precision than model.pt, but in fact they use the same datatype (Float32). The problem is therefore because of the image pre-processing.

I have solved it using proportional scaling with padding instead of unproportional image resizing.